# ASP.NET Website Administration tool not opening

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, administration

When trying to use the Login Control from VB.NET and click on 'Administer Website' the T Website Administration tool is not opening.

Im using VS 2012 Professional and SQL-Server Express 2012

Any idea why this is happening?

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>


<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Trying to enter the link manually into the browser:

```
http://localhost:64309/asp.netwebadminfiles/error.aspx
```

got me this error on the web page:

```
An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Default browser used for the project.

It seems it doesn't work in Firefox, but when tried in IE, it works fine.